# Composer specifying 'in development' packages?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I am working on a project with multiple local git repositories that tie together into a single app. Pretty much like Symfony has different components our app is split up similarly.

My question is, what is the proper way to link to these packages?

I know I can do something like this:

```
"repositories": [
    { "type": "path",  "url": "../another-component" },
    { "type": "path",  "url": "../yet-another-component" }
]
```

This still forces me to do `composer install` to pull in the packages though. It clones the local git repository that I am using for development whenever I run `composer install`.

Obviously I do not want to do this every single time I adjust a component that makes up a part of my main app to pull in any changes I have done to repositories that make up my main app repository.

Is there a better way to keep development repositories in sync with each other? Or can I tweak this to get what I want?

I am guessing a lot of developers run into this problem so there must be a well thought out solution for this?

Cheers.

**Edit**

I have also seen this article which goes over the same concept:

http://tech.vg.no/2014/11/25/using-local-packages-as-composer-dependencies/#comment-522050

The problem is that everytime you make changes to one of the repositories that make up your app you have to run: `composer update` which is a hassle. I am really looking for a way to just keep them properly in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution works fine, I had to delete my lockfile and clear the composer cache though. Instead of cloning a repository composer will make a symlink and your repositories will be kept in sync.

It might not be advisable to delete your lockfile so if anyone has a better suggestion please post a comment.